# UIImageView DROP (with Jerk) animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

How can I create a UIImageView DROP (with Jerk) animation in Objective-C similar to the cover page animation in this app (the way BAT drops from top right hand side on the cover page)?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFl7V9YtbSg&feature=player_embedded#!

I tried animating on y-axis but it doesn't work very good.

Comment: I think it was made using Cococs2d , and the bat is a sprite

Comment: Thanks George. Is there a way to achieve same functionality using objective-c?

Comment: If you need to animate UIView try some animations

Answer (score 2):

Set start frame to your view and then do something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
        animations:^{ 
            myView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height); // where x, y are new coords
        } 
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
        }];
```

If you need exact the same animation you should implement it yourself , using a few animations  one after another

Answer (score 0):

A key frame animation may be what you need. The effect you are trying to achieve is really an animation from point A to point B, then up a little (the "jerk") to point C, then back to point B. Key frame animation lets you specify all these points, where the (very convenient) `UIView` `-animateWithDuration:` methods generally only support animating a property from a starting value to an ending value (and that property could be the origin x or y, the alpha, and a number of other things.) You could chain multiple `-animateWithDuration:` calls together, but that might begin to get complicated quickly if you have too many animations to chain together.

Have a [look at this article](http://blog.hawkimedia.com/2012/03/animation-revelation/) I wrote recently about key frame animation, complete with [example project](https://github.com/granoff/KeyFrameAnimation) (on Github).